# Site not indexed in Google, but indexed in Bing and Yahoo

Tags: google-search, search-engine-indexing, bing, yahoo, google-index

When I search for mytgp.ph on Google, I don't get any relevant results. But when I search using Yahoo or Bing, the site is the 1st result on the first page. Any ideas?

Here's my `site:mytgp.ph` query on Google:
[image]

Comment: Comes up just fine for me. If you're logged in to a Google account, what happens if you log out and try the search again? It might just be that your personalized results aren't showing the site or are showing it much further down in the listing, for whatever reason. Have you tried digging a few pages in?

Comment: I used another browser to query the site and I am currently not logged into my Google account on that browser (FF). I can't dig in because it is a password protected site and the home page should be enough.

Comment: Try running the query 'site:mytgp.ph' perhaps that will work for you?

Comment: I meant that it might not be showing on the first page of the search results. (When I searched for just "mytgp" rather than the domain, you were pushed to the third page in.) You've got two reports so far that this is just you. Voting to close unless you can provide something else that makes this an actual problem.

Comment: I tried site:mytgp.ph and it returns 0 results (Google search) for me. The site has been up since Dec '11 and I even linked it to some of my "older" sites just to give it an extra push. @Su': I wouldn't ask for help here if I saw it a few search pages in since I know it is a relatively new site. I posted it here because my query returns 0 results, which is weird because Yahoo and Bing lists it just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a local problem, I just [ran this query](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&cp=8&gs_id=2&xhr=t&q=mytgp.ph&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&site=&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=mytgp.ph&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=cee598fc631c5c56&biw=1920&bih=979) and you appear in the first spot.

Google customises your results by country (even by local area in the UK and US, can't speak to other countries) so sign out of your google account, **delete all your cookies and cached data** and then try again.

You can run a site spesific query using `site:mysite.com` [site:mytgp.ph](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=site:mytgp.ph&pbx=1&oq=site:mytgp.ph&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1249998l1254979l0l1255673l13l10l3l0l0l0l101l631l9.1l13l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=cee598fc631c5c56&biw=1920&bih=979) that should show all the indexed pages of your specific site.

Beyond that sign-up for [webmaster tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/), which after a period of time should show data about your site's ranking.

[image: Photo of google result]

Comment: I ran your query and still no relevant result. :(

Comment: I've added a picture to demonstrate. Can you try on your mobile phone, or another computer on a different connection?

Comment: Thanks for the image.  I'll try another device and see how that goes. Could the country i'm in be a factor?

Comment: It's possible, you could also try deleting all your cookies, did you see my comment about searching for site:mytgp.ph?

Comment: Yes, I already tried site:mytgp.ph and I don't get any results. I've been doing this for years and this is the first time Google refuses to index a page (for me anyway).

Comment: Well this is strange indeed. Do you get results for other sites using a different query?

Comment: Yes, when I query other sites, I get the expected results. And yes I already linked this to my Webmaster account last Dec '11 (SOP for me).